# How to set Document Types in XCode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I have an iPhone app, and I would like it so that when a user clicks on a .pdf file as an email attachment, my App is one of the options to open it with. After some research, it seems that I need to add a Document Type in the info.plist. Problem is, I cannot find ANY tutorials explaining how to use the new Document Type GUI:

Image here:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: While it doesn't cover this particular graphical way of setting document types in Xcode's UI, my answer to the question [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) shows how to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This "Document Types" editor feature may be so new (was it introduced in 4.2) that the documentation sloths haven't had time to write anything about it.

I did find [this Technical Q&A document that describes "How do I get my application to show up in the 'Open in...' menu on iOS for a specific document type?"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1587/_index.html), which basically introduces the Xcode developer to the Document Types editor.

[And more low level documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html).

If you understand these basics and can figure out how to edit a raw Info.plist file, you should be good to go!

I hope this information helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @trojanfoe. hopefully I've corrected my link to be a lot more useful.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there's still no official documentation on this. With the help of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290) describing how to write the info.plist file, I came up with this in Xcode 4.5.1:

[image]

This set of properties seems to be the minimum to get your app to run by tapping on an email attachment.

Answer (score 4):

It should be sufficient to set the "Name" field to "Portable Document Format" and the types field to "com.adobe.pdf".

Comment: This worked for me on Xcode 4.5.1 with the exact strings you gave.